# Concatenate strings in python in multiline

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I have some strings to be concatenated and the resultant string will be quite long. I also have some variables to be concatenated.

How can I combine both strings and variables so the result would be a multiline string?

The following code throws error.

```
str = "This is a line" +
       str1 +
       "This is line 2" +
       str2 +
       "This is line 3" ;
```

I have tried this too

```
str = "This is a line" \
      str1 \
      "This is line 2" \
      str2 \
      "This is line 3" ;
```

Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Which python are you using 2.x or 3?

Comment: @ipinak python 2.7.6

Comment: do you want each line to be a separate line (ie: should there be a newline after `"this is a line"`, and after `str1`, etc?)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

There are several ways. A simple solution is to add parenthesis:

```
strz = ("This is a line" +
       str1 +
       "This is line 2" +
       str2 +
       "This is line 3")
```

If you want each "line" on a separate line you can add newline characters:

```
strz = ("This is a line\n" +
       str1 + "\n" +
       "This is line 2\n" +
       str2 + "\n" +
       "This is line 3\n")
```

Comment: Don't forget the opening and closing parenthesis!  That stumped me for a bit.

Answer (score 47):

## Python 3: Formatted Strings

As of **Python 3.6** you can use so-called "formatted strings" (or "f strings") to easily insert variables into your strings. Just add an `f` in front of the string and write the variable inside curly braces (`{}`) like so:

```
>>> name = "John Doe"
>>> f"Hello {name}"
'Hello John Doe'
```

To split a long string to multiple lines surround the parts with **parentheses** (`()`) or use a **multi-line string** (a string surrounded by three quotes `"""` or `'''` instead of one).

### 1. Solution: Parentheses

With parentheses around your strings you can even concatenate them without the need of a `+` sign in between:

```
a_str = (f"This is a line \n{str1}\n"
         f"This is line 2 \n{str2}\n"
         f"This is line 3")  # no variable in this line, so a leading f"" is optional but can be used to properly align all lines
```

**Good to know:** If there is no variable in a line, there is no need for a leading `f` for that line.

**Good to know:** You could achieve the same result with backslashes (`\`) at the end of each line instead of surrounding parentheses but accordingly to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you should prefer parentheses for line continuation:

> Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

### 2. Solution: Multi-Line String

In multi-line strings you don't need to explicitly insert `\n`, Python takes care of that for you:

```
a_str = f"""This is a line
        {str1}
        This is line 2
        {str2}
        This is line 3"""
```

**Good to know:** Just make sure you align your code correctly otherwise you will have leading white space in front each line.

---

**By the way:** you shouldn't call your variable `str` because that's the name of the datatype itself.

**Sources for formatted strings:**

- [What's new in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)
- [PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Answer (score 22):

Python isn't php and you have no need to put `$` before a variable name.

```
a_str = """This is a line
       {str1}
       This is line 2
       {str2}
       This is line 3""".format(str1="blabla", str2="blablabla2")
```

Comment: This will include the leading whitespace on each line, which is different than what the current code does.

Comment: I did not took that in consideration since the initial code provided didn't worked.

Comment: Btw... removing the leading whitespaces is as starting every line at col 1

Answer (score 4):

I would add everything I need to concatenate to a list and then join it on a line break.

```
my_str = '\n'.join(['string1', variable1, 'string2', variable2])
```

Comment: This wouldnt solve my purpose.Because I am writing a script to which will take a variable name and generate a getter and setter method for it.SO I would want to write in the sae format.

Comment: @user3290349 this solves the question that you asked, and has room for expanding. If you want it to solve a different purpose, ensure that purpose is stated in your question.

Comment: @user3290349 in python there is no need for getters and setters. I suggest taking a look at python's `@property` decorator. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property