# Writing a one line string in multiple lines in Python

Tags: python

Let's say you need to write a long string for a function, assigning a variable, or just simply printing it. Since according to PEP8 standards a line can't have more than 120 characters, it would be useful to know how I can write it as multiple lines, but still keep it as one line when printing/assigning the string.

Example:

```
print("This is an extremely long string that is definitely much, much longer than any kind of PEP8 standard would allow because wow this is too long for one line, PEP8 is right.")
```

I tried searching the web for solutions, but Google misinterpreted my response and gave the `\n` escape sequence as a solution, which is the exact opposite of what I want.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34296091/5741041

Comment: `print("""This is an extremely long
       string that is definitely much, much longer 
      than any kind of PEP8 standard would allow
       because wow this is too long for one line,
       PEP8 is right.""")` with this you can use any lines your want

Comment: Also, if you're using a well supported IDE/editor like PyCharm, for example, it will do this for you just by hitting enter where you want to break the line.

Comment: You can continue the string on the next line without using the newline character `\n`. This way, when you print or assign the string, it will be treated as a single line without any line breaks. `print("This is an extremely long string that is definitely much, "
      "longer than any kind of PEP8 standard would allow "
      "because wow this is too long for one line, PEP8 is right.")`.  Pay attention as I write this in the comment section. It's not truly visible; make sure to press Enter after each closing double quote in your IDE.

Comment: @AchilleG in a multiline string the line breaks bacome _part of the string_, which doesn't appear to be what the OP wants.